# datamembers password not hashed?

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, web-services, hash

I am trying to hash/salt my datamembers passwords in my datacontracts but when I add a new student and then GET that student collection the password field hasnt been hashed/salted it comes back as what I typed?

```
    public void AddStudent(Student student)
    {

        student.StudentID = (++eCount).ToString();
        byte[] passwordHash = Hash(student.Password, GenerateSalt());

        student.TimeAdded = DateTime.Now;
        students.Add(student);
    }
```

Can anyone help fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should assign hashed pasword to student password then add student.

```
public void AddStudent(Student student)
{
    student.StudentID = (++eCount).ToString();
    byte[] passwordHash = Hash(student.Password, GenerateSalt());

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(byte b in passwordHash){
        stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
    }

    student.TimeAdded = DateTime.Now;
    student.Password= stringBuilder.ToString();;
    students.Add(student);
}
```

Comment: hmm if I try that I cant convert `byte[]` to `string` if I change the datamember to `public byte[] Password;` then I get a 400 bad request when I try to add a new student with password ARGH never ending!

Comment: Simply store the byte array ;-)

Comment: how? I use a stringbuilder when POST AddStudent (see updated code)

Comment: just use this this link to convert hashed byte array to string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766038/how-to-convert-c-sharp-hashed-byte-array-to-string-for-passing-to-api

Comment: @Gandil still not sure how to do that with my method?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add this to your [orginal question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263464/wcf-rest-hash-salt-datamember-field/10263563#10263563), but here is some more code:

```
[DataContract(Name="Student")]
public class Student
{
    [DataMember(Name = "StudentID")]
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    // local non public cache
    private byte[] _password;
    [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
    public byte[] Password {
        get { return _password; }
        set {
            this.Salt = GenerateSalt();
            this._password = Hash(value, this.Salt);
        }
    };
    [DataMember(Name = "Salt")]
    public byte[] Salt;

    // ...
```